# How to set up WinSCP to transfer a file to a remote ABCI server

Tags: putty, scp, winscp

Hello I am trying to connect to a ABCI System User Environment and I cannot perform a scp to save my life. I have tried two approaches; 1) is use unbuntu linux bash command for windows (the app you have to install from the window store). and the second approach is with WinSCP and Putty.
I have generated a public key and loaded up on the ABCI system. And I can tunnel into the server and login correctly and view files. But when I try to upload a zip file to the server I get denied access. Can someone help me set up the WinSCP correctly to tunnel into the server?

Here is the information that I have

For the tunnel ssh

```
local port: 11022
remote host and port: es.abci.local:22
remote port: 22
```

For a session

```
hostname: as.abci.ai
```

And in putty this is all set up and works perfectly. As I followed this directions https://portal.abci.ai/docs/en/02/
But I still cannot scp a file into my local folder how can I do that? Thank you for any help with this.

Oh and I do know for putty scp I need to use this instead of the typical scp

```
pscp -scp -P 110022 myFile.zip myusername@localhost:/place to copy to/
```

I found out how to get the logs from WinSCP
These are the log output

```
2019-05-21 14:06:54.720 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey
. 2019-05-21 14:06:54.720 Offered public key
! 2019-05-21 14:06:54.738 Server refused our key
. 2019-05-21 14:06:54.782 Server refused our key
. 2019-05-21 14:06:54.782 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey
. 2019-05-21 14:06:54.902 [Tunnel] Closing connection.
. 2019-05-21 14:06:54.902 [Tunnel] Sending special code: 12
. 2019-05-21 14:06:54.902 [Tunnel] Sent EOF message
. 2019-05-21 14:06:54.902 Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
* 2019-05-21 14:06:54.966 (EFatal) Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
* 2019-05-21 14:06:54.967 Authentication log (see session log for details):
* 2019-05-21 14:06:54.967 Using username "abc10808va".
* 2019-05-21 14:06:54.967 Server refused our key.
* 2019-05-21 14:06:54.967 
* 2019-05-21 14:06:54.967 Authentication failed.
```

Comment: So are you able to update the ZIP file anyhow?

Comment: The host you are connecting to is localhost:11022. If you can connect to it over ssh, then scp should work the same.. unless the path you need to save is not writeable by your username.

Comment: I am sorry I meant upload. I have been trying to set up Winscp but am a bit lost in what to set. I tried many different combinations.

Comment: You still didn't really explain, if you have any reason to believe it should even work. Did you talk to your server administrator?

Comment: Yes but he wont help set up winscp. He said if I can ssh in then i should scp in, which i know is true so its a issue of how I put in the settings in winscp i think

Comment: But you can **connect** with WinSCP (equivalent to *"can ssh"*). You cannot **overwrite files**. Does the Admin have an explanation for that?

Comment: I can connect with putty but not with winscp. So I have to make a tunnel which I can do fine. Then in another putty i can login to the systems fine. This is all in ssh. But when I try to scp a file from my local computer to the server it rejects my public key.

Comment: I do not see any mention of a rejected key in your question.

Comment: I have finally found how to look at logs from WinSCP

Comment: And do you have any reason to believe the key should work? Can you authenticate using the key anyhow? E.g. using PuTTY or any other SSH client?

Comment: I can log into the server and look around with ls and cd I can also mkdir and rm -r items as well when I ssh. I need to upload my public key to the server which I have done. And then use my private key locally in putty. Then it lets me on no problem. Is that what you mean?

Comment: So you open a tunnel and then you connect to that tunnel with PuTTY and authenticate using that private key?

Comment: I think that is what I do. I am not too sure about that scp and networking with remote systems

Comment: How are you creating the tunnel? Using PuTTY? Show us PuTTY event logs for both the tunnel session and the session, in which you connect using that tunnel.

Comment: I see in the putty logs which took me a while to figure out I found that it says the server refused the public key. But then why can I look around the server and access data there? If it did not accept the key

Comment: I recreated the public key and redid all the steps to access the ABCI server. I made logs for both the tunnel and the client and both say that they accept the key and I can log in no problem. I now need to set up the SCP issue

Comment: Looking up host "localhost" for SSH connection
Connecting to ::1 port 110022
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.71
Failed to connect to ::1: Network error: Connection refused
Connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 110022
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1: Network error: Connection refused
Network error: Network error: Connection refused
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Network error: Connection refused

Comment: That is what I get when i try a scp from a cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer for this, I was a lot of trial and error changing the setting on WinSCP I appricate everyone help on this. I will describe how I set up every thing.

1. Make a pub/private key with putty gen.
2. Load that up on the ABCI webpage
3. In WinSCP set up information.
4. Hostname: es.abc1.local:22 with port number 11022
5. In advance settings go to Connection->Tunnel
6. Hostname: as.abci.ai; port number 22; local tunnel port 11022
7. Add you private key from puttygen

Then you should be all set.